# Limit popular posts by days

Tags: posts, get-posts

I am using this get_posts array to retrieve top 15 popular posts by comments. The problem is that it shows those all those highly commented posts from the day posts were added into blog. So, the list sometimes changes but most of the time remains same.

How can I limit/show posts of the last 7 days?
This would show most commented posts of the last week.

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
global $post;

$args = array(
'orderby' => 'comment_count',
'order' => 'DESC' ,
'numberposts' => 15);

$popular_posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $popular_posts as $post ) :

if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
<li>

<div class="widgetimg">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('widgetimg-thumb'); ?></a>
</div>

</li>
<?php } endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: anyone here to tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function which show the posts of last 7days or you can change it according to your requirement.

```
function filter_where($where = '') {
        //posts in the last 7 days
        $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')) . "'";
        return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

Comment: The OP will need to use `'suppress_filters' => FALSE` in the get_posts arguments I believe. Maybe you can improve your answer with a fuller example?

Comment: how to add it ? I have a foreach loop and get_posts array.

Comment: Before your query just add this function or call this function it work on both ways and it show you post of last 7days.

Comment: Thanks @Adi, it worked. but the only thing is get_posts suppresses filters by default. So, there's need to put suppress_filters => FALSE in get post array.

Comment: @MereDevelopment can you provide reference url for above answer? I couldn't find it in wordpress codex.

Comment: @10wtaylor Hi, there's reference to it under the first Note in Parameters here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts